# Condition on column visualfoce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, conditional

Is it possible to render column values based on condition in a visualforce page? I tried

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!b.account.name == !a.account.name}">
    <apex:column value="{!b.name}"/>      
</apex:outputText>
```

Error:

> Incorrect parameter type for function 'not()'. Expected Boolean,
>   received Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `An <apex:column> component must always be a child of an <apex:dataTable> or <apex:pageBlockTable> component`.

But you can do like this.

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!cont}" var="b">
<apex:column value="{!b.name}" rendered="{!IF(b.account.name == a.account.name,true,false)}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

[refrence `<apex:column>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_column.htm)

Comment: Your welcome ...

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `!a.account.name`. You don't need to precise a second '!' character.

Here's the right way to use a conditional expression in visualforce:

```
rendered="{!IF(b.account.name = a.account.name,true,false)}"
```

Comment: An <apex:column> component must always be a child of an <apex:dataTable> or <apex:pageBlockTable> component. can't be surround by <apex:outputText  >  right?

Comment: @NITHESHK  Indeed this is not working?  ' <apex:pageblockTable value="{!cont}" var="b">      
<apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(b.account.name = a.account.name,true,false)}">
    <apex:column value="{!b.name}"/>      
  </apex:outputText>    
</apex:pageBlockTable> '

Comment: @jenssen Yes Exactly

Comment: @Jenssen i have added answer , rendered directly you can use in <apex:column>